# Why is my scripts.js file not connected? They are in same folder, the name is 'scripts' not 'script'. Script is after the body in index.html

Tags: html, jquery, css

<!doctype html>

Multi Level Dropdown

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
...................

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard to understand your problem based on the context you gave. Consider to be more precise and share all of your code. However a couple of ideas:

1. Your `<script>` tag should be placed within the `<body> ... </body>` tag
2. Use `<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>`
3. Check/ confirm whether your stylesheet "style.css" is working
4. Check for valid javascript code by testing with simple code such as `alert('Test');` in your scripts.js file